# Converting and Importing Google Earth Layer with KML Styles into GeoServer (SLD Format) - Styling Discrepancy

Tags: gis, kml, geoserver, google-earth, sld

I am  facing a challenge while trying to import a layer from Google Earth into GeoServer. The styles in Google Earth are in KML format, while GeoServer requires SLD format for styling. As a result, the imported layer in GeoServer does not retain the original styles from Google Earth. I need guidance on how to successfully import the layer from Google Earth into GeoServer while preserving the styling.

I have explored options like manually recreating styles, using third-party conversion tools, and custom scripting. However, I am unsure which approach is the most effective and reliable. Additionally, I would like to understand any potential limitations or considerations when converting KML styles to SLD format.

Comment: You need to write an old file and upload it. There is no way to import the kml styles